# Nested loops: Still $\mathcal O(n)$?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I have an algorithm similar to this:

```
i=1
while(i < n) {
  //something in O(1)
  while(i < n && cond) {
    //something in O(1)
    i++
  }
  i++
}
```

Where "cond" is some condition which can be checked in $\mathcal O(1)$. It is clear that this algorithm is $\mathcal O(n^2)$. But is it also $\mathcal O(n)$?

I'd say yes because the statement "i++" is executed $\mathcal O(n)$-times since both loops end when i reaches n.

Is it possible to rewrite the algorithm in a form with equivalent runtime so that it can be seen more clearly?

Comment: There are assumptions to this problem that you are _not_ making.  Let's assume that `cond = false` always, then the initial operation can be `i = i - 1`.  This will cause this program to never end (to not halt) and thus there is no big-Oh you can give to this program.

Comment: The statements in between do not modify i. i is only modified in "i=1" and "i++".

Comment: Our reference questions on [algorithm analysis](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) and [Landau notation](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use/61#61) may shed some light.

Comment: @ljfa _"The statements in between do not modify i. i is only modified in "i=1" and "i++"."_  This is an assumption you did not make clear, you have: `//something in O(1)`.  `i = i - 1;` is in $\mathcal{O}(1)$.  It could also be in $\mathcal{\Theta}(1)$ if that $\mathcal{O}(1)$ operation was say `i = n;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there is not a true nested loop. It's one loop with, what is equivalently an if-test in there, like:

```
while(i<n){
   if(cond)
      //something Θ(1)
   else
      //some other Θ(1) thing
   i++
}
```

Notice in your case, you have the same variable for both loops with no reset.

So, to answer your question, the running time is $\Theta(n)$.  In particular, it is $O(n)$.

As a commenter states, anything that is $O(n)$ is also $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Your pseudocode implies a $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ runtime.  Your reasoning is correct though.

Comment: $O(n^2)$ denotes an upper bound. So anything that is $O(n)$ is also $O(n^2)$. In your first sentence you seem to confuse $O()$ with $\Theta()$.

Comment: @d'alar'cop Your reasoning is flawed then--it cannot be simply put into an $\mathcal{O}(1)$ for each loop--you need something more sophisticated.

Comment: I think your loop is correct--I just think you need to do a little more to justify it...I'm giving an answer as such.

Comment: "NB: I'm guessing that what you intended was $\Theta$, not $O$." That seems very unlikely. Anything that is $\Theta(n^2)$ is definitely not $\Theta(n)$ so it would be odd to ask about that. But something that is $O(n^2)$ may very well be $O(n)$ so that is a reasonable question.  (Quicksort is $O(2^n)$!)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think perhaps we suffer from some kind of misunderstanding... "Anything that is Θ(n2) is definitely not Θ(n) so it would be odd to ask about that. " actually that's exactly what makes me think it was more likely.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That being said, i understand your point. I come from stackoverflow,  where you would perhaps understand my response better